# What git command could be used to check when a remote branch was created?

Tags: git

Git is used at work. The number of branches is growing and growing. The aim is to remove branches that are older than X weeks.

**Attempt 1**

Running `git branch -h` will probably indicate what to run to check when a branch has been created.

```
user@localhost $ git branch -h
usage: git branch [<options>] [-r | -a] [--merged | --no-merged]
   or: git branch [<options>] [-l] [-f] <branch-name> [<start-point>]
   or: git branch [<options>] [-r] (-d | -D) <branch-name>...
   or: git branch [<options>] (-m | -M) [<old-branch>] <new-branch>
   or: git branch [<options>] [-r | -a] [--points-at]

Generic options
    -v, --verbose         show hash and subject, give twice for upstream branch
    -q, --quiet           suppress informational messages
    -t, --track           set up tracking mode (see git-pull(1))
    --set-upstream        change upstream info
    -u, --set-upstream-to <upstream>
                          change the upstream info
    --unset-upstream      Unset the upstream info
    --color[=<when>]      use colored output
    -r, --remotes         act on remote-tracking branches
    --contains <commit>   print only branches that contain the commit
    --abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s

Specific git-branch actions:
    -a, --all             list both remote-tracking and local branches
    -d, --delete          delete fully merged branch
    -D                    delete branch (even if not merged)
    -m, --move            move/rename a branch and its reflog
    -M                    move/rename a branch, even if target exists
    --list                list branch names
    -l, --create-reflog   create the branch's reflog
    --edit-description    edit the description for the branch
    -f, --force           force creation, move/rename, deletion
    --merged <commit>     print only branches that are merged
    --no-merged <commit>  print only branches that are not merged
    --column[=<style>]    list branches in columns
    --sort <key>          field name to sort on
    --points-at <object>  print only branches of the object
```

**Attempt 2**

This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches was found, but this is not an option as it removes branches without checking the age.

Comment: Git doesn't store creation date of branches afaik.  Is it ok to remove branches that haven't been *committed to* recently?

Comment: @XiongChiamiov What is your definition of `recently`?

Comment: Whatever it is you want.  The important part of that sentence is "committed to" versus "created".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Note: this answer shows how to find branches that have been *updated* a long time ago, not branches that have been *created* (i.e., spliced off of some parent) a long time ago. I believe this is what the OP actually wanted (as opposed to the title he chose for the question), as this would lead to good candidates for deletion.*

You have to recall that a branch in git is nothing "physical". It is, by definition, and literally, *only* a simple text file in `.git/refs` which only has its file name (which is the branch name) and the hash of the tip/head commit. It has no date information or *anything* else.

So `git branch` will not help you here.

The object type that has dates associated with it are commits, in git. So you have to list commits. This is done with `git log`.

So a working command would be:

```
git log --remotes --before 2018-01-01 --no-walk --decorate
```

You can read up the details on https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log , but in short, it means

- `--remotes`: start with any and all remote branches (substitute `--branches` for local branches)
- `--before ...`: only list commits older than the date given
- `--no-walk`: only list the very first commit for each branch, don't walk back the history
- `--decorate`: display all tag and branch names associated, just in case

This will give you all branch heads that are older than your given date.

Comment: The branches older than X are shown (+1), but also some details. Would it also be possible to just return the branch names, like the output of `git branch`?

Comment: See this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325599/delete-all-branches-that-are-more-than-x-days-weeks-old

Comment: Sure, @030, the `--format` option can be used to only output the ref (branch) names, if needed. Vorsprung also linked a duplicate question which uses little bash scripts to iterate over the branches and deletes stuff.

Comment: this command show only tracked remote branch not all remote.